# Start new feature with existing name using Smartgit

Tags: git, git-flow, smartgit

When using GitFlow with SourceTree I was able to start a new feature using a name that was once a feature. But using SmartGit it restricts me from doing that.

[image: SmartGit restriction]

Is there a possible configuration flag I can alter so it will allow that or is this definitely not possible?

Comment: This is currently not possible with SmartGit. You might consider to post an RFE at: https://smartgit.userecho.com/

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. Here is the post: https://smartgit.userecho.com/topics/426-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why SmartGit wasn't able to create a feature branch with an existing name was that I forgot to delete the old feature branches. You have to check "Delete feature branch" after finishing the feature so you don't have to do it afterwards by hand.

[image: Finish feature]

If the old and finished feature branch was deleted, you can recreate a feature with the same name.